# API for scrolling one Gb rtf document in swing app

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, text, scroll

Need to make scrollview in swing app with rtf document that is more than one gigabyte. Can u suggest some api that shows only a pice of view and other part of document is in some buffer or cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a one gigabyte document you're going to render only part of it at a time. A general approach would be to stream read part of the document and render that part, then stream in more as the user scrolls down. You could try to read the document piece by piece to determine the total height if you want to the scrollbar to work correctly. You need to implement your own virtual memory paging scheme so that you do not need to keep the entire one gigabyte document in memory, plus the memory required to render it.